# Backtraking Sudoku Java

Tags: java

.

Hola y buenas a todos, vengo por orientación.

Como dice el titulo,estoy intentando realizar BackTraking a un Sudoku en Java, pero no me resulta, lo estoy desarrollando en netbeans.

Código: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1IQLkF78ejEYff3gJsgZZJDBDZcCDAsOE/view?usp=sharing

Este código es donde debo realizar el BackTraking.

```
private boolean sudo() { 
    char aux = ( (char)(0+48) ) ;
    for( int x = 0 ; x < r.length ; x++ ) {             // recorremos la matriz
       for( int y = 0 ; y < r.length ; y++ ) {

           if( r[x][y] != aux ){}                       // si la posicion actual es distinta a cero, no hacer nada

                                                        // como la posicion actuales iguala cero 
           for( int z = 1 ; z <= 9 ; z++ ) {            // se recorre la matriz uscando una posible solucion
               aux = ( (char)(z+48) ) ;
               if( sinConflicto( x , y , aux ) ) {      // se pregunta si el valorno genera conflicto

                   r[x][y] = ( (char)(z+48) ) ;         // se almacena el valoren la posicion actual

                   if( sudo() ) {                       // se pregunta si el sudoku ha sido resuelto
                       return true ;
                   }

                   r[x][y] = ( (char)(0+48) ) ;         // posicion actual con valor cero para volver a buscar otra solucion

               }                    
           }
           return false ;
       }   
    }
    return true ;

} // fin sudo
```

Espero que me puedan orientar en donde estoy haciendo las cosas mal.

Saludos.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Tene en cuenta que netbeans es solo una ide, lo podrias estar desarrollando en cualquier cosa y no cambia el sentido de la pregunta. Respecto a eso, solo mostras una funcion, pero no queda claro cual es tu problema. Podrias ser mas claro en cual es el mismo?

Comment: Interesante propuesta para lo que pretendes. Hace tiempo utilicé algo similar (matrices tridimensionales) para resolver sudokus. Normalmente se usan algoritmos tipo *swordfish*, pero con *backtraking* siempre caes en matrices 3D. Si consigo la fuente de lo que implementé hace tiempo veo de echarte una mano. Saludos

Answer (score 0):

.

Hola y buenas a todos, ya pude resolver mi inconveniente con BackTraking, les dejo el código a insertar.

```
private boolean sudo( int n ) { 
    for( int i = 0 ; i < r.length ; i++ ) {                       // for i     
        for( int j = 0 ; j < r.length ; j++ ) {                   // for j

            if( r[i][j] != '0' ) {                                // posicion actual es distinto de cero
                continue ;                                        // continuar
            }

            for( int k = 1 ; k <= 9 ; k++ ) {                       // for k para las posibles soluciones
                if( sinConflicto( i, j , (char)(k+48) ) ) {         // si el valor k en la posicion actual da verdadero
                    r[i][j] = (char)(k+48) ;                        // almacenar valor k en la posicion actual

                    boolean b = sudo( n ) ;                         // 
                    if( b ) {                                       // se resolvio el sudoku
                        return true ;                               // devuelve verdadero
                    }
                                                                    // si la condicional no se activa, se asume que arrojo falso
                    r[i][j] = '0' ;                                 // posicion actual con valor cero
                }
            }

            return false ;  
        }   
    }

    return true ;

} // fin sudo
```

Saludos.